# MinGW and @N dll functions linking

Tags: gcc, dll, linker, mingw

I have the '.h' file with content like this:

```
#ifndef MY_IMPORT
    #define MY_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport) /* !!! */
#endif

#ifndef MY_EXPORT
    #define MY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"{
#endif

MY_IMPORT VOID* WINAPI XXX_FUNC( VOID * ARG1, ... );

/* ... */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and I have the 'lib.dll' library, which exports XXX_FUNC without @N suffix.

When I try to build my dll (mydll.dll) wich uses this lib.dll I have got GCC message:

```
undefined reference to `__imp__XXX_FUNC@12'
```

I looked many tons of internet, including stackoverflow but I can't find the solution.
Linker called as:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup mydll.o -L. lib.dll -o mydll.dll
```

As I can find, the GCC must try to link the '_*imp*_XXX_FUNC@12' to '_*imp*_XXX_FUNC', and '--enable-stdcall-fixup' is only option that prevents warnings on such conditions, but my MinGW GCC don't try this.

I have installed MinGW with GCC v4.7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the dll with the `declspec(dllexport)` active. You should replace `MY_IMPORT` and `MY_EXPORT` with this:

```
#ifdef _DLLifdef BUILDING_MY_DLL
# define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
# define MY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

When building statically, just

```
#define MY_API
```

How you determine that, is up to you and your build system. I've seen various ways to do that. Then you add `MY_API` to each symbol you want exported:

```
MY_IMPORT VOID* WINAPI XXX_FUNC( VOID * ARG1, ... );
```

This will cause the DLL to contain the symbol

```
__imp_XXX_FUNC...
```

with some other stuff. Note the `__imp_` that is added due to the `dllexport`.

Yes this is archaic (see e.g. GCC's `visibility` attributed), but this is how Windows works.

Comment: I define '#define MY_IMPORT __declspec(dllexport)' when I compile core dll, and don't define this when try to compile another dll, which uses core dll, so MY_IMPORT automaticaly defines to __declspec(dllimport) as written in header. Problem occurs when I try to link another dll that uses core dll